# Animated show where there are 3 kids and the main kid can transform using bracelet and crystals

Tags: story-identification, animation

I am looking for this one show that was on Netflix back in 2013-16 I believe there were three kids and the main character finds this bracelet that, with a stone, can transform into an orange monster. In one of the episodes they go to a museum and end up with the stone army and end up in a plane, but then get teleported to a different dimension and help a panda who is the original owner of the statues. They fight an enemy and the main character receives his stone so he can transform into the panda. In another episode they are in a pyramid where he receives an Egyptian god's stone so he can turn into the Egyptian god.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Without sentences and punctuation this is a bit hard to follow; you would get a better response if you [edit] this to be a bit more clear.